# socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: php, sockets, redis, plesk

I am getting the error as `socket_bind()` error after the server was restarted, I tried to restore the default to 0.0.0.0 and also to the Server IP Address but still the same issue

Please kindly help with your valuable thoughts and suggestions

```
PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/module/Admin/src/Controller/DeviceController.php on line 157
```

The Code

```php
ob_implicit_flush();
$reqObj = $this->getRequest();
$ethAddr = $reqObj->getParam('ethaddr', 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'); // default to 0.0.0.0
$port = $reqObj->getParam('port', 222); //default to 222

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $ethAddr, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
```

Stack trace :

```
PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /module/Admin/src/Controller/DeviceController.php on line 157
Exception writing to Cassandra: Exception: Alert message does not exist for oozt" in /library/AlertMsg/AlertMsg.php:75
Stack trace:
#0 /library/AlertMsg/AlertMsg.php(107): AlertMsg\AlertMsg->getAlertMsg()
#1 /library/Device/DeviceCommunicationDriver.php(275): AlertMsg\AlertMsg->getSmsAlertMsg()
#2 /library/Device/DeviceCommunicationDriver.php(136): Device\DeviceCommunicationDriver->changeStatusMsg()
#3 /library/Device/DeviceCommunicationDriver.php(64): Device\DeviceCommunicationDriver->sendMsg()
#4 /module/Admin/src/Controller/DeviceController.php(190): Device\DeviceCommunicationDriver->processDeviceData()
#5 /vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(71): Admin\Controller\DeviceController->readUdpDataAction()
#6 /module/Admin/src/Controller/AppController.php(42): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch()
#7 /vendor/laminas/laminas-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(319): Admin\Controller\AppController->onDispatch()
#8 /vendor/laminas/laminas-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners()
#9 /vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(97): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil()
#10 /vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(132): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch()
#11 /vendor/laminas/laminas-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(319): Laminas\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch()
#12 /vendor/laminas/laminas-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners()
#13 /vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/Application.php(325): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil()
#14 /public/index.php(42): Laminas\Mvc\Application->run()
#15 {main}
PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /module/Admin/src/Controller/DeviceController.php on line 157
PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /module/Admin/src/Controller/DeviceController.php on line 157
PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /module/Admin/src/Controller/DeviceController.php on line 157
```

Comment: Does `socket_bind($sock, '0.0.0.0')` succeed?

Comment: Sorry no, that also failed with an error, can we give the Static IP Address and see if resolves?

Comment: I didn't pass the port arg, are you sure that's what you tried? Was it the same error? If so, what I can think of is that when this script runs, the OS does not have an IP (such as the network service not running yet), but this is a bit unbelievable.

Comment: So, how do we check if the network service is running,  maybe, that is a good catch

Comment: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking

Comment: Here's a related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278155/network-service-failed-to-start-lsb-bring-up-down-networking-centos-7